# After adding an Azure Function Project to Solution some tasks.json file settings have been removed

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I have a small issue and I'm not sure if I added an Azure function project to my workspace/solution correctly.
I have a solution, in it I have 4 projects, an API (DotNet Core), client (Angular), Core (class with models and interfaces), Infrastructure (EF, DB, services).

I wanted to add an Azure function project to this solution/workspace and I did so by creating a folder called 'Azure' as seen in green, then I clicked on my Azure Extention, then clicked 'Add New Project' and walked through the steps. It created it successfully and all the files are in the folder. I can run the function and receive messages in it! Good ok!

[image]

Here are my Azure function extension options

[image]

**PROBLEM** - Now when I go to debug the website application (Angular/.Net Core) and I start up the Angular server and then debug/launch, I should have the compiler build me a new API.DLL, but it doesn't! And I see a error message pop up showing this

[image]

I can see my tasks.json file has been modified.

Here is tasks.json before I added the Azure function. You can see build label for the API.csproj info

```js
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [{
      "label": "build",
      "command": "dotnet",
      "type": "process",
      "args": [
        "build",
        "${workspaceFolder}/API/API.csproj",
        "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
        "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
      ],
      "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
    },
    {
      "label": "publish",
      "command": "dotnet",
      "type": "process",
      "args": [
        "publish",
        "${workspaceFolder}/API/API.csproj",
        "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
        "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
      ],
      "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
    },
    {
      "label": "watch",
      "command": "dotnet",
      "type": "process",
      "args": [
        "watch",
        "run",
        "${workspaceFolder}/API/API.csproj",
        "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
        "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
      ],
      "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
    }
  ]
}
```

And here is tasks.json after I add the function project, where the build label for the DotNet Core API has been removed! Now only Azure Function data is in it.

```js
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [{
      "label": "watch",
      "command": "dotnet",
      "type": "process",
      "args": [
        "watch",
        "run",
        "${workspaceFolder}/API/API.csproj",
        "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
        "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
      ],
      "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
    },
    {
      "label": "clean",
      "command": "dotnet",
      "args": [
        "clean",
        "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
        "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
      ],
      "type": "process",
      "problemMatcher": "$msCompile",
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/Azure/Functions"
      }
    },
    {
      "label": "build",
      "command": "dotnet",
      "args": [
        "build",
        "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
        "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
      ],
      "type": "process",
      "dependsOn": "clean",
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      "problemMatcher": "$msCompile",
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/Azure/Functions"
      }
    },
    {
      "label": "clean release",
      "command": "dotnet",
      "args": [
        "clean",
        "--configuration",
        "Release",
        "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
        "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
      ],
      "type": "process",
      "problemMatcher": "$msCompile",
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/Azure/Functions"
      }
    },
    {
      "label": "publish",
      "command": "dotnet",
      "args": [
        "publish",
        "--configuration",
        "Release",
        "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
        "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
      ],
      "type": "process",
      "dependsOn": "clean release",
      "problemMatcher": "$msCompile",
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/Azure/Functions"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "func",
      "dependsOn": "build",
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/Azure/Functions/bin/Debug/net5.0"
      },
      "command": "host start",
      "isBackground": true,
      "problemMatcher": "$func-dotnet-watch"
    }
  ]
}
```

**FYI** It looks like my tasks.json file is all tweaked up and modified!
It looks like the dotnet build propoerties have been overwritten by the Azure function properties. If I copy and paste back in the old tasks.json file, it works fine. Should the addition of this new Azure function project have removed all my properties for the other parts of the app?

**QUESTION** - It seems like this isn't the best way to add an Azure Function Project to an existing workspace/solution. So what is the prescribed way and is there a tutorial or link somewhere I can follow as everything on the Microsoft site just shows new standalone function projects by themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some quick digging and I found this in the `vscode-azurefunctions` repo

```js
private insertNewTasks(existingTasks: ITask[] | undefined, newTasks: ITask[]): ITask[] {
    existingTasks = existingTasks || [];
    // Remove tasks that match the ones we're about to add
    existingTasks = existingTasks.filter(t1 => !newTasks.find(t2 => {
        if (t1.type === t2.type) {
            switch (t1.type) {
                case func:
                    return t1.command === t2.command;
                case 'shell':
                case 'process':
                    return t1.label === t2.label && t1.identifier === t2.identifier;
                default:
                    // Not worth throwing an error for unrecognized task type
                    // Worst case the user has an extra task in their tasks.json
                    return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }));
    existingTasks.push(...newTasks);
    return existingTasks;
}
```

By the looks of it, the extension will try to replace existing tasks if they match in `type`, `label` and `identifier`, rather than trying to extend them; which in my opinion would be the sensible thing to do for something as common as `process` and `build`.

So you are correct, your `tasks.json` is being updated by the extension upon creating a new func project, using the wizard offered by the extension. And I honestly think this is a bug, one you probably want to report to them directly [at the vscode-azurefunctions repo](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azurefunctions/issues). Also, the code in question [can be found here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azurefunctions/blob/dfb792c36ff128aa8daeff5bae8697c338645f63/src/commands/initProjectForVSCode/InitVSCodeStep/InitVSCodeStepBase.ts#L123-L145).

Alternatives to reporting the issue as a bug and waiting for resolution:

- Make tasks.json read only (yikes)
- Use the func core tools to [create new func projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows%2Ccsharp%2Cbash#create-a-local-functions-project)

With Func Core Tools you can use `func new` from the folder you want your function in (using a terminal of your liking). It will let you choose a worker runtime (dotnet, js, python etc.), and the name of the project. It will not interfere with your existing `tasks.json`.

Comment: HI ELI. I've submitted a issue to the site and I'll see if they respond. In the meantime I have a couple of questions for you. 1. Is my scenario uncommon? It seems like it would be very common considering devs like me would want to use referenced projects that the Azure Function calls, so including it in a solution with other projects would be common? 2. Do you know of any other ways to add an Azure Function project to a solution with other projects in it? Maybe there's another way and I'm unaware of it?

Comment: Lastly, I'm not sure what you mean by "give you original task a different identifier" and then try it. When you say "identifier", do you mean "label" as I don't see any "identifier" name. What I can say is I copy/pasted the original task.json info back into the file after I added the Azure project and it works fine

Comment: I can't say if it's common. But from personal experience, then yes, I've added several function projects to existing solutions, where a shared lib is used both by an API, the function project and maybe even something 3rd. But I only use VS2019 Enterprise. This seems to be related specifically to the vscode extension.
As I stated in the answer, you could use the func core tools to add new func projects to your existing code. Should be doable (from what I remember), and it won't touch your `tasks.json`.

Comment: I've updated the answer, hopefully it better explains how you could try with a unique `identifier`.

Comment: Hi Eli - Just a quick update. I tried to add a unique "identifier" but intellisense is throwing a warning saying "User defined identifiers are deprecated. For custom task use the name as a reference and for tasks provided by extensions use their defined task identifier." But, using a unique identifier, I was able to add the new Azure Function properties to task.json without deleting the old. But again, in order to run the dotnet project (not the Azure Function), I have to comment out the Azure Function stuff from task.json.

Comment: Alright, I'd say remove `identifier` again and go with my suggestion of `func new` instead, using func core tools. I've updated my answer to reflect this. And then just wait for a better resolution from the issue you opened in the extension's repo.

Comment: Hi Eli. Thanks for the edit and explanation. "It will not interfere with your existing tasks.json" you are right as I tried it, but it doesn't incorporate the launch.json info and a few other items. I'll wait to see if I can get some type of response from MS.